# deducting one class from the template class in template c++

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following problem:
I have a class in which i need to determine the type of an object in function of the template class:

```
template<class a_type> class inputPort_varExp{
protected:
RTT::InputPort<a_type> inport;
RTT::InputPort<a_type_der> inport_derivative;
...
```

in my case, i would like to automatically deduct the a_type_der with the  following logic:

- if typeid(a_type)==typeid(Frame) then  typeid(a_type_der)=typeid(Twist),
- if typeid(a_type)==typeid(double) then  typeid(a_type_der)=typeid(double),
- etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the "type traits" concept here.

This has the advantages of being a compile-time solution (no runtime errors due to missing some type specific code), and it avoids the need to edit your inputPort_varExp class for each type you pass in as a_type.

The idea is you create a template class / struct to map one type to another:-

```
template< typename t > 
class DerivativeTrait
{
    public:
    typedef DerivativeType t;
    //this provides a default derivate...
    //you'd need to decide if that was a safe thing to do
};
```

You can then specialize that trait class:-

```
template<> 
class DerivativeTrait<Frame>
{
    public:
    typedef DerivativeType Twist;
};
```

you can now use this in your inputPort_varExp to define a_type_der:-

```
typedef DerivativeTrait<a_type>::DerivativeType a_type_der;
```

note since C++11 you could use the using keyword instead of typedef.

Some other options:

If you are able to edit the types you pass in to inputPort_varExp, you could just add a typedef to those classes - this wouldn't work for your case since you pass double in as a_type.

Another simple alternative is to add an extra template parameter for a_type_der, but that doesn't prevent an incorrect combination (e.g. Frame and double).

You might also want to consider decltype, if the type can be deduced by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @ROX
Code for future references

```
template< typename t >
class DerivativeTrait
{
    public:
    typedef  t DerivativeType;
};
//special cases: Frame and rotation

template<>
class DerivativeTrait<KDL::Frame>
{
    public:
    typedef  KDL::Twist DerivativeType;
};


//the class where the derivative is needed

template<class a_type> class inputPortDerivative_varExp{
protected:
    typedef typename  DerivativeTrait<a_type>::DerivativeType a_type_der;
    RTT::InputPort<a_type> inport;
    RTT::InputPort<a_type_der> inportDerivative;
... 
};
```